# ColdFusion - xmlParse error - premature end of file

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I have a file that queries orders and writes them out in xml to be polled by some software that reads the order into an erp system. It reads fine but I can't parse an xml response back that will update order status with xmlParse , it throws an error. I get the software response xml with GetHTTPRequestData().content fine. I just can't do anything with it there. As soon as I add xmlParse it errors out.

I can write out the response to a seperate file and work on it there , but it get's overriden on the next iteration.I'm looking for an alternate solution. Is there any way to create some code to "catch" the xml in the seperate file I write or post it to ,  but not have the the code that will update my status table overwritten each time the request is sent?

This is not a web service , just plain xml with http post 's.Tks.

Comment: Have you tried running the XML response in MSIE? Its parser is sometimes useful in finding the offending error

Comment: You could always use a [temp file](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c60.html). However, that is just a band-aid. If it happens consistently, better to figure out the real cause. What is the actual `content` returned?

Comment: Thanks James. Leigh, it's XML. However , when trying to parse it the error breaks the page. To test that the response is good I wrote it to a separate file and confirmed the xml is being sent. xmlParse seems to be the culprit here

Comment: But what does the raw content look like? *Might* be an encoding problem, but it would help to see what it is that is breaking XMLParse.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SetOrderStatus>
<WebOrderNumber>322571</WebOrderNumber>
<DocumentNumber>322571</DocumentNumber>
<Status>F</Status>
<Reason>Item number: APALI22 not found in ICITEM table for customer: BLO02A</Reason>
</SetOrderStatus>`

Comment: One thing I did notice in IE and FF viewing the xml source is that line 1 is always blank. The xml always starts on line 2. Another thing I came across in my research is that it could be a possible bug in CF with a BOM (byte order mark) being sent over with it. I tried a Trim() and Reg Ex on it but it didn't help.

Comment: Could be. What are the ascii values of the characters in the first line?

Comment: How can I view it raw? I tried saving the source  as txt , but I doesn't do what I thought. Any other way to get the raw values?

Comment: Depends on whether `GetHTTPRequestData().content` is binary or string. But assuming string, just loop `from=1` to=`len(string)` and use `mid(string, index, 1)` to grab the current character on each iteration. Then dump its `asc(...)` value.

Comment: Tks Leigh. I tried changing the charset type to see but go nothing. I'm kind of stuck because I can't do anything in the file that gets the xml response , thus writing it to a separate file via <cffile> tag. It only writes the xml out to that file so there is limited checking under the hood. It seems a simple thing to create some xml to be read and be able to read back a response in the same file. I'll let you know if I find anything. Tks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46287/discussion-between-leigh-and-steve)